# Parsing tokens with PLY

Tags: python, regex, parsing, token, ply

I've been trying to parse some given text with PLY for a while and I haven't been able to figure it out. I have these tokens defined:

```
tokens = ['ID', 'INT', 'ASSIGNMENT']
```

And I want to classify the words I find into these tokens. For example, if the scanner is given:

```
var = 5
```

It should print this:

```
ID : 'var'
ASSIGNMENT : '='
INT : 5
```

This works just fine. The problem is when the program is given the following text:

```
9var = 5
```

The output for this would be:

```
INT : 9
ID : 'var'
ASSIGNMENT : '='
INT : 5
```

This is where it goes wrong. It should take 9var as an ID, and according to the ID regex, that is not a valid name for an ID. These are my regular expressions:

```
def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*' 
    return t

def t_INT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

t_ASSIGNMENT = r'\='
```

How can I fix this?

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say: "It should take `9var` as an ID". But then you point out that `9var` doesn't match the ID regex pattern. So why should `9var` be scanned as an ID?

If you want `9var` to be an ID, it would be easy enough to change the regex, from `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*` to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+`. (That will also match pure integers, so you'd need to ensure that the INT pattern is applied first. Alternatively, you could use `[a-zA-Z_0-9]*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*`.)

I suspect that what you really want is for `9var` to be recognized as a lexical error rather than a parsing error. But if it is going to be recognized as an error in any case, does it really matter whether it is a lexical error or a syntax error?

It's worth mentioning that the Python lexer works exactly the way your lexer does: it will scan `9var` as two tokens, and that will later create a syntax error.

Of course, it is possible that in your language, there is some syntactically correct construction in which an ID can directly follow an INT. Or, if not, where a keyword can directly follow an INT, such as the Python expression `3 if x else 2`. (Again, Python doesn't complain if you write that as `3if x else 2`.)

So if you really really insist on flagging a scanner error for tokens which start with a digit and continue with non-digits, you can insert another pattern, such as `[0-9]+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*`, and have it raise an error in its action.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It worked pretty well! What I had to do was to define a new case (a new pattern), just as you suggested. Thank you!